# How to create bamboo plugin with java11

Tags: maven, bamboo, java-11

I am creating bamboo plugin with java11 and maven project.

mvn clean install is returning success status with below NPE

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at aQute.bnd.osgi.Processor.quote(Processor.java:1322)
    at aQute.bnd.header.Attrs.append(Attrs.java:404)
    at aQute.bnd.header.Parameters.append(Parameters.java:172).......
```

when tried uploading plugin in bamboo 6.8.1 with java11 then it throws failure error.

Firstly tried on hello world plugin as well as per pom.xml mentioned in URL:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/Create-bamboo-plugin-tutorial/qaq-p/686456

```
<properties>
 <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
 <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
 <bamboo.version>6.2.3</bamboo.version>
 <bamboo.data.version>6.2.3</bamboo.data.version>
 <amps.version>6.2.3</amps.version>
 <plugin.testrunner.version>1.2.3</plugin.testrunner.version>        
 <atlassian.spring.scanner.version>1.2.6</atlassian.spring.scanner.version>
 <atlassian.plugin.key>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId} 
 </atlassian.plugin.key>
</properties>
```

expecting bamboo plugin should get build without any error and should get upload successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bamboo doesn't work with Java 11 yet. So plugin should be built with Java 8 as well